# Change image .style in javascript only works with Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change the style of an Image in a javascript.

So if I click on the picture, the javascript gets started and should erase the style content. This works in Firefox, but not in Chrome for example. Does anyone know why?

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<div>
    <img id="testpic" src="26.png" onclick="changeDirection()" style="transform:scale(-1,-1);-webkit-transform:scale(-1,-1);-moz-transform:scale(-1,-1);-o-transform:scale(-1,-1)"/>
</div>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

function changeDirection() 
{   
    document.getElementById('testpic').style="";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your html is not well-formed: the div is positioned between `head` and `body` elements, should be part of `body`.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting issue. Apparently Chrome ignores attempts to redefine `style` property, which is supposed to be an object ([`CSSStyleDeclaration` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration)), not a string. In this sense Firefox behavior seems inconsistent.

This will work everywhere:

```
function changeDirection() {
    document.getElementById('testpic').style.cssText = "";
}
```

Or maybe better to empty (or remove) style attribute:

```
document.getElementById('testpic').setAttribute('style', '');
document.getElementById('testpic').removeAttribute('style');
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using jquery ?

Here how I would do this:

```js
$(function() {
    $('#testpic').click(function() {
       // when the user clicks on the img testpic, jQuery will either remove or add (toggle) the class on the image
       $(this).toggleClass('change-direction');
    });
});
```

```css
/* I move all style definition inside a class to make code clearer */
.change-direction {
  transform:scale(-1,-1);
  -webkit-transform:scale(-1,-1);
  -moz-transform:scale(-1,-1);
  -o-transform:scale(-1,-1)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Click on the image:
<img
    id="testpic"
    src="http://www.larevueautomobile.com/images/Ford/Shelby-500GT/Exterieur/Ford_Shelby_500GT_009.jpg"
    class="change-direction"
    width="100"
    height="100"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help.

With removing the content of style it works now in Chrome too! Thanks.

Does anyone know why viewport behaves differnt with Chrome and Firefox ( and standard Android Browser ).

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=1715, target-densitydpi=high-dpi">
```

I have this code. ( Yes I need the hardcoded width ).

In Firefox everything is fine.
In Chrome and standard Internet it seems to be fine, but there are scroll bars, so it displays about I think 1300 in width, and for the rest I have to use the scroll bars, does someone know why ?

Thanks